# Colorimetry at home?

Tags: home-experiment, concentration

Is there a reasonably priced option for colorimetry at home? Is this even a good option to accomplish my goal?

I'd like to roughly determine the concentration of a chemical in an ethanol extract from a natural product. It has a definite color. I would be able to buy small quantities of the purified product from a chemical supplier. Based on my recollections of college chemistry, I should be able to make a solution of known concentration and compare them with a colorimeter to determine how much I've extracted. Would this be reasonable, or should I be looking at another way of doing this?

Comment: If you have a colorimeter yes. If you are a hobbyist with electronics, yes. In the worst case you can try to get where your solution stand in between two known concentration. For all this you need an analytical scale and some volumetric flasks.

Comment: I appreciate the help.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have looked into different options to try to get an idea of costs and availability. For anyone else looking at doing home colorimetry an analytical scale is less than 20 USD on Amazon, as are small volumetric flasks. A used spectronic 20 is less than 200 USD on ebay (sometimes substantially less), and it appears that there are several website guides to 'build your own spectrophotometer'.

Comment: To make the solutions, the volumetric flasks are ok, but to compare them you will need Nessler cylinders.